# Lint error on Okio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I started getting this errors about

```
**InvalidPackage: Package not included in Android**

../../../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.6.0/98476622f10715998eacf9240d6b479f12c66143/okio-1.6.0.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in **Android: java.nio.file**. Referenced from **okio.Okio**.
```

I am using:

```
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

I did some reading on the same at following links:

https://github.com/square/okio/issues/58

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/896

I have 2 questions for the same

**Question 1 ::** What change could have introduce this error ?
    The code was compiling Okay previously, I don't think upgrading Gradle to 2.10/2.11 or upgrading Android studio 2.0 beta 4/ AS 2.0 beta 5 could have introduced this error. As i tried to revert everything back. But i was still getting same error!

**Question 2 ::** I don't wish to disable lint or add following quote in my app. What is the best way to stop this error from happening?

```
lintOptions {
    warning 'InvalidPackage'
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable the warning specifically for this error by creating a lint configuration file:

```
<lint>
    <issue id="InvalidPackage">
        <ignore regexp="okio-1.6.0.jar"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

And then apply that configuration in your build file:

```
android {
    ...

    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file("lint.xml")
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: remember to use the same version of okio jar as it is in error log > `okio-1.6.0.jar` in this case, I had to change to `1.11.0.jar`

Comment: This just tells us how to mask the problem - still don't understand what it means or why we need to mask it! Thanks anyways

Comment: You can generalise the `"okio-1.6.0.jar"` regular expression to `"okio.*jar"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try add this into build.gradle

```
android {
...

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

kevinpelgrims' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35815080/1071320) can be generalised so that you don't have to remember to modify your `lint.xml` file every time you update the Okio library in your project, as follows:

```
<lint>
    <issue id="InvalidPackage" severity="error">
        <ignore regexp="okio.*jar"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

And your `build.gradle` is as per other answers in this thread, i.e.

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        lintConfig file("lint.xml")
    }
}
```

I stumbled across the above lint xml snippet in [this](https://github.com/square/okio/issues/58#issuecomment-232811171) Github comment.